# Page Setup Tools is Disabled - PrintPreview

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a spreadsheet that has a macro. Within this macro there is a Userform. This userform has a button that when pressed opens the print preview of data in a spreadsheet. When I execute the "PrintPreview" method, **all buttons the page setup tools are disabled**, as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Below is the code I'm running

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

**The code below is inside UserForm1**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MySheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set MySheet = Worksheets("Plan3")

MySheet.Select
MySheet.Range("$A1:$AI166").Select
MySheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$AI$166"

ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Me.Hide
MySheet.PrintPreview
Me.Show
End sub
```

**I couldn't find the reason why the Page Setup Tools buttons is disabled. Can someone help me?**

**Note 1**: This code is inside a userform. The userform is loaded into the Workbook_Open() event.

**Note 2:** When I open the spreadsheet by double clicking on the file, the userform is loaded automatically. Clicking the CommandButton1 button displays the print preview screen, **however the Page Setup Tools buttons is disabled**.

If I open the Visual Basic editor and run the Workbook_Open(), clicking the CommandButton1 button shows the print preview screen and **the Page Setup Tools buttons are enabled**. That is, **if the macro runs with the Visual Basic editor open the problem does not happen**.

**Note 3:** This is only happening in the 2007 version of excel.

**Note 4:** I did a test by opening UserForm1 in "(vbModeless)" mode. In this case the problem did not occur. However in the application I am developing, I need to open the userform in "(vbModal)" mode.

Comment: Where is the code located? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: OK, I updated the code

Comment: But where is the code? In a procedure? In an Event? In a Module? In a Userform?

Comment: The code is inside a procedure that is inside a userform.

Comment: Hi PeH, I updated the code and entered more details regarding the problem.

Comment: Ok, I created a new workbook with a worksheet "Plan3", added a userform with a button and added the `Workbook_Open` and `CommandButton1_Click`. Then I close the workbook and open it. The code runs, the form is modal and if I click the button the form hides and all buttons in the preview are enabled. I cannot reproduce your issue in Excel 2019. • Try exactly what I described above. If this reproduces your issue then it might be a bug in your specific Excel version. Make sure you update to the latest verison. If it is a bug and not an issue in the code we probably cannot help you.

Comment: OK, i think this may be a limitation of the 2007 version of excel. I will change my approach and use another technique. Thank you for your support.